# Have JSDoc generate documentation for private (non-exported) functions in module

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am using the JSDoc generator to generate some good looking documentation for my project in which I am using AMD modules.

In my project I have some modules that contain functions that are not exported so they cannot be used from outside the module. When generating the JSDoc, these functions are not included in the documentation.

I created the following example module to illustrate my example:

```js
/**
 * Example foobar module
 * @module foobar
 */
define([], function () {

    /**
     * Returns foo
     * @returns {string} - The string "foo"
     */
    function foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    return {
        /**
         * Returns bar
         * @returns {string} - The string "bar"
         */
        bar: function(){
            return "bar";
        }
    }
});
```

When I generate documentation for the above module, only the `bar` function is included in the documentation, whereas I would also like to have the `foo` function included in my documentation and marked as private.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: This is tested on JSDoc 3*

There are two parts to this:

- Get JSDoc to generate code for the nested function
- Get JSDoc to generate code for the private member

#### Get JSDoc to generate code for the nested function

```
/**
 * Returns foo
 * @memberOf module:foobar
 * @returns {string} - The string "foo"
 */
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}
```

By default, nested functions are not documented. To do so, add the `@memberOf` directive. This forces JSDoc to document the function as a member of the module. Notice the `module:` prefix - this is a standard.

This should make `foo` show up as under the `Methods` section of module `foobar`.

#### Get JSDoc to generate code for the private member

Now, just mark the function as private. To do this, use the [`@private`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html) directive.

```
/**
 * Returns foo
 * @private
 * @memberOf module:foobar
 * @returns {string} - The string "foo"
 */
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}
```

You'll notice that the documentation now *again does not contain* the method `foo`. This is because JSDoc ignores private members by default. To generate code for private members as well, use the `-p` command line option.

```
jsdoc foobar.js -p
```

Now foo shows up as a `(private, static)` method in `foobar`, while `bar` is just `(static)`.

Comment: Cheers! Didn't know about the -p flag yet!

Comment: how would I go about telling JSDOC that it's a memer of a class inside that module? I've tried memeberof module:Foo.Bar and memeberOf Foo.Bar

Comment: I tried adding the `private` flag to the API, but it does not work: `jsdoc2md.render({ files: './dist/test.js', private: true }).then(console.log)` Any idea why?

Comment: Same problem, private doesn't work neither as command line option nor inside the config file... is jsdoc just broken or was it removed?